# How to Swap Cathode with Anode in LED MATRIX 5X7 In proteus?

Tags: led, proteus, led-matrix

Hi in Proteus 8 the given model of Led Matrix 5x7 has Anode on Column side and Cathode on Row side.
I want swap it and Hence Column would have Cathode and Rows will have Anode and my Second Connection Start working(which is now not working) Unlike the one working now and turning the Led on.
Any Help would be Appreciable 
:)[image: Proteus Imaage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the led matrix model has cathodes to the rows and anodes to the columns. To change right click on the matrix object and open the properties (edit properties menu item).

[image]

Click "Edit all properties as text" and replace `{INVERT=A,B,C,D,E,F,G}` with `{INVERT=1,2,3,4,5}`.

[image]

Now the model will have anodes to the rows and cathodes to the columns

Comment: Oh Thank you very Much.
I put 50 Not gates(because making connecting 10 matrixes) to do that and i was finding it messy.
Therefore i thought of asking it and this site comes to my mind.
And my Problem is resolved.

Comment: @HümayunOkhtar Place one matrix on the schematic, change it and then create 9 copies of it rather than editing 10 components.

Comment: Thank you so much.I started editing them one by one and just read your comment.